# How to ignore send email to Rows that have Value after getting new Google Form submissions?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want the **function** that will make my script ignore send merge emails to the previous emails that I collected using Google Form when someone new submits his information.

Here is the script I'm using:

```
function sendMail() {
  const emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("form1");
  const startRow = 2
  const data = sh.getRange(startRow, 2, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn() - 1).getValues();
  data.forEach((row, i) => {
    emailTemp.fullname = row[1];
    emailTemp.phone = row[2];
    let htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
    let emailSent = row[6];
    if (emailSent != "EMAIL_SENT") {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(row[0],"Thank you!","Your email doesn't support HTML.",{ name: "Email App", htmlBody: htmlMessage });
      sh.getRange(startRow + i, 6).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
    }
  });
}
```

I want to ignore all the **Rows** that have **EMAIL_SENT** *value* in the Column **F** :
[image: example]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That's what this line is for  `if (emailSent != "EMAIL_SENT") {`

This  `let emailSent = row[6];` should be this `let emailSent = row[4];`

Your row starts at column 2 according to your original question.